# Fedora 20 Elantech Touchpad not working

Tags: fedora, touchpad, toshiba

I just purchased a *Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100* laptop, installed *Fedora 20*, and cannot get the touchpad to work.
Here's my environment:

```
Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100
ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
```

---

```
uname -r
3.13.8-200.fc20.x86_64
```

---

```
dmesg | grep mouse
[    0.687578] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.491139] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x381f01)
[    1.518222] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x14, 0x0c.
```

---

```
xinput --list | grep Touchpad
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

---

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep syna
[    25.548] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    25.548] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    25.548] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.548] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[    25.570] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: found clickpad property
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3097 (res 31)
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 1793 (res 31)
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[    25.570] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[    25.580] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    25.580] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    25.580] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.056
[    25.580] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
```

---

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on
# non-synaptics clickpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a logical explanation of how I managed to fix this issue. All I can say is that after a few reboots and no significant changes, especially related to the issue, the touchpad started working.